# AdMob in ListView

Tags: android, admob

Does anyone know how to add an AdView of admob in a list view?

Comment: As in have every list item contain an ad?

Comment: I think he means putting an ad in place of one of the list items or every so often interspersed in the list

Comment: see this tutorial [Embedding AdMob Adverts in Android ListViews](http://blog.uncommons.org/2011/05/09/embedding-admob-adverts-in-android-listviews/)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to write your own list adapter (extend `BaseAdapter<?>`), and return an AdView from the adapter's getView() method. getView() gives you the position of the View that is being created, so you can just check the position and return an AdView wherever you want, and inflate the normal View for the other positions.

Answer (score 0):

http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/embedding-admob-ads-within-listview-on.html

Even though I think something's off with the height calculation

Answer (score 0):

I've been using admob with a listview as well.

That's the code I am using:

http://www.ahotbrew.com/how-to-put-admob-banner-on-the-bottom/